# Why hardware accelerated View Canvas is slower than SurfaceView Canvas in Android?

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview, hardware-acceleration

As a proof of concept we have built two Android applications which draw 4000 circles on a canvas and move them 1 pixel every frame.

The first one, uses a SurfaceView and calls holder.lockCanvas() to obtain the canvas and update it.

```
while (isRunning) {
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    Canvas canvas = null;
    try {
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

        if (canvas != null)
        {
            synchronized(surfaceHolder) {
                gamePanel.update();
                gamePanel.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (canvas != null)
            try {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

The other application overrides a View and uses the method onDraw(canvas) to update the scene.

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        ballGroup.draw(canvas);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

The circles are drawn inside the object `ballGroup` which has an array of coordinates for each of the circles.

```
for (Ball ball : balls) {
    canvas.drawCircle(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, ball.paint);
}
```

As it is stated in the Android documentation, the canvas of the custom View is hardware accelerated whereas the SurfaceView Canvas is not. However, the results of the experiment show that the framerate is higher using the SurfaceView.

We know the canvas of the view runs on the UI thread and the SurfaceView runs on a separate thread. Nevertheless, we would expect the performance to be better due to the hardware acceleration in the Custom View Canvas but it is not. Is our assumption wrong or are we missing something else?

Comment: Can you explain in detail how you are drawing your circles?

Comment: @MorrisonChang I've added it to the answer. We use the method canvas.drawCircle() for all the 4000 circles in a loop. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The fact that `SurfaceView` runs on its own thread is likely a big part of it, since it doesn't get tangled up with all the user interaction from the UI thread. It is going to be much more efficient with rendering in general since it owns its own window and doesn't play nicely with all the other `View`s in the hierarchy. It is simply designed to render efficiently.